# How did my moon roof and all my windows open without anyone driving, touching or not being in the car in 2 -3 days?

Tags: electrical, honda, accord

I have a 2009 Honda Accord EX 4 cylinder. Nobody had driven my car in 2 days, all windows were closed including the roof and the car was locked. On day 3 I left my driveway in another car and I noticed as we were pulling out that my moonroof and all windows were open. How did this happen? My remote doesn't even open my windows or moonroof. My doors were all locked also. 
Who opened my entire car without even being near it ?

Comment: Had to have been a poltergeist. J/K! That's pretty crazy.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 my thoughts exactly or someone's playing a prank. i lean towards the ghost.

Comment: creeepaaayyyyy. Glad you got an answer.

Answer (score 5):

According to the 2009 Honda Accord [Owner's Manual](http://owners.honda.com/vehicles/information/2009/Accord-Sedan/manuals), your car is capable of opening the windows and moonroof with the remote transmitter.

[image]

This is most likely the cause. The may have been pressed for accidentally in a fashion that triggered this feature.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and you are absolutely right! I was able to duplicate what had happened. You know your stuff. Thanks man.

Answer (score 2):

Did you have the keys/remote in your pocket? Some cars (e.g. my VW Golf VR6) can open windows etc if you hold down the open button for several seconds. Did kids play with remote?

Comment: The OP stated "My remote doesn't even open my windows or moonroof." Also, this is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: I didn't have a specific button on my remote for my golf for the windows, but, the functionality was there if you held the button down for long enough - some cars holding down the lock button for several seconds will cause any open windows to close as well.

Comment: That may be the case for your VW, but is that the case with a 2009 Honda Accord? Did you research is that capability is even available for that car? If so, by all means share it and it will validate your answer. We want to be careful we aren't making the assumption the OP doesn't know about their own car/remote. This is another example of why using comments is good for getting clarification before posting answers.

Comment: As you say "Do the research"... Perhaps the OP should read the manual before starting the engine...